# How to solve this error (missing $)

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to create this table in LaTeX:

[image]

and receive this error:

> Error: ! Missing $ inserted.

I can't change much of the tabularx stuff as it's in the template. How do I solve this error? My code:

```
<inserted text> 
                $
l.120 \end{tabularx}

\begin{table}[h]

\tbl{Mechanical properties of cortical bone obtained from tensile testing and small punch test}

\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lll@{}}

\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

Location & Elastic modulus (\textit{E})  & Stiffness (\textit{k})  \\
& GPa & N/mm\\

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

Upper & 12.47 \pm $0.79^{b}$ & 309.27\pm $19.266^{b}$\\

Middle & 15.54\pm $1.45^{a,b}$ & 517.76\pm$22.241^{a,b}$\\

Lower & 9.48 $\pm$ 0.63 & 235.84\pm17.477\\

Overall & 12.49\pm 2.67  & 356.91\pm123.91\\

ANOVA & p \textless 0.05 & p \textless 0.05\\

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline

\end{tabularx} %line 120.

$^a$Indicates a statistically significant difference compared with upper location of  bovine femur (p \textless 0.05).\\

$^b$Indicates a statistically significant difference compared with lower  location of bovine  femur (p \textless 0.05).

\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You have forgotten the signs `$...$` on `\pm`. See **Lower** and *Overall*. Can you add your MWE, please?

Comment: Hey Sebastiano!! Thanks for the A2A. I have edited the question and attached the image of the solution I require.

Comment: This is at least the third question of yours where the problem is math symbols used outside of math mode.

Comment: If you are using unicode, you can write ± without introducing math mode. If they are French people reading this, with the bepo ergonomic keyboard layout, you have even direct access to ± : AltGr+7.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed your code to be error free. You'll still have to add the table lines. As the comments said your main problem was the `\pm`
Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Mechanical properties of cortical bone obtained from tensile testing and small punch test}
\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lll@{}}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Location & Elastic modulus (\textit{E})  & Stiffness (\textit{k})  \\
& GPa & N/mm\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Upper & $12.47 \pm 0.79^{b}$ & $309.27\pm 19.266^{b}$\\
Middle & $15.54\pm 1.45^{a,b}$ & $517.76\pm22.241^{a,b}$\\
Lower & $9.48 \pm 0.63$ & $235.84\pm17.477$\\
Overall & $12.49\pm 2.67$  & $356.91\pm123.91$\\
ANOVA & p \textless 0.05 & p \textless 0.05\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabularx} %line 120.
$^a$Indicates a statistically significant difference compared with upper location of  bovine femur (p \textless 0.05).\\
$^b$Indicates a statistically significant difference compared with lower  location of bovine  femur (p \textless 0.05).
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your table design remain me to `threeparttable`, so I suggest to use it. With it you can simply add table notes on the end of table. With `siunitx` package is very handy to write your numbers with given uncertainty and with rules from `booktabs` you can make table more beautiful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
             table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{a,b}}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Mechanical properties of cortical bone obtained from tensile testing and small punch test}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{X
                                S[table-format=2.2 (3)]
                                S[table-format=3.3 (5)]}
    \toprule
Location& {Elastic modulus (\textit{E})}    & {Stiffness (\textit{k})} \\
        & {GPa}                             & {N/mm}\\
    \midrule
Upper   & 12.47\pm 0.79\textsuperscript{b}  & 309.27\pm  19.266\textsuperscript{b}\\
Middle  & 15.54\pm 1.45\textsuperscript{a,b}& 517.76\pm  22.241\textsuperscript{a,b}\\
Lower   &  9.48\pm 0.63                     & 235.84\pm  17.477\\
ANOVA   & {$p < 0.05$}                      & {$p < 0.05$}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx} %line 120.
    \begin{tablenotes}\tiny\smallskip\raggedright
\item[a] Indicates a statistically significant difference compared with upper location of  bovine femur $(p < 0.05)$..
\item[b] Indicates a statistically significant difference compared with lower  location of bovine  femur $(p < 0.05)$.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I shring table width to `0.8\linewidth`. If you prefer to have its width equal `\textwidth`, than for width use only `\linewidth`.

[image]

**Edit:** instead of `\textless` is better to use `<`. With added `\blindtext` is now visible position of table in a (dummy) text.